# Update back button in navigationbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

if i change the title of the parentViewController, how do i update the back button displayed in the upper left corner of the child view. ?

i already know to set self.title when i am actually displaying the parent view, but i would like to know how to refresh the button with the new title displayed in the child view while i am looking at the child view. i have tried

```
self.parentViewController.title = @"foo"
```

and

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.title = @"foo"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was implementing a delegate protocol. my child view tells the parent the new name and the parent sets its title. with self.title = @"foo"

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
self.parentViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"foo";
```

Comment: to clarify, i think all of the listed methods, including yours, 'set' the barItem...but i can't get it to update without popping the parent view

Comment: Delegation, at first thought, seemed like overkill, but it worked perfectly. I couldn't get this working, but if you post one that does or just change your answer to 'use a delegate' i will mark this as correct. someone should get something, i figure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the title for the navigationItem that belongs to the 'previous' controller. So in a navigationController that would be the one 'to the left'.

You can set this title first and then push the new view onto the stack.

Comment: That is what jacob does, sans pushing a new view onto the stack. I suppose I am not being clear. While i am in the child view, i want to update the back button. Is the only way to do this by making a new button and replacing the old back button?

Comment: With child view you mean a subview of the view that is currently on top of the navigation stack? If that's the case, I think Jacobs way should work. Strange...